# Flutter gradient particle color lerp without ColorFilter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flame

I have the following particle with color lerp over time

```
class Particle extends ImageParticle {
  final Color _start;
  final Color _end;
  final Paint _paint;

  Particle({
    required super.image,
    required Color start,
    required Color end,
    super.lifespan,
  })  : _start = start,
        _end = end,
        _paint = Paint();

  @override
  void render(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.scale(2 * Curves.decelerate.transform(1 - progress));
    canvas.drawImageRect(
      image,
      src,
      dest,
      _paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    _paint.colorFilter = ColorFilter.mode(
      Color.lerp(
        _start,
        _end,
        Curves.decelerate.transform(progress),
      )!,
      BlendMode.modulate,
    );
    super.update(dt);
  }
}
```

But I need to reassign the color filter each update. I know that assigning a new Paint each update has a big performance impact and from tests I see that assigning a ColorFilter each update also has a performance impact. Mostly because it causes the garbage collector to have spikes on web. Is there a way to lerp the color without having to reassign a color filter each update?

The docs show to do it in the following way

https://docs.flame-engine.org/1.5.0/flame/rendering/particles.html?highlight=particle#computedparticle

But this will give the same issue.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do this any more efficiently currently unfortunately. Only way I could come up with is to precalculate a lot of ColorFilter's for the wanted colors and round to the closest one when you pass in the the progress.
Good point about the docs, they should be updated to create the Paint object outside of the render method.

Comment: @spydon with the lag spikes games have become unplayable on web. I think you are right for now we need to precalculate a list. In that case I will make a flutter feature request for some sort of color tween with the paint.